# How to check if Wikipedia Article is Featured or not using API?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I need to check if a Wikipedia Article is Featured or nor. How to do that using Wikipedia API?
If this is not supported, is there a Wikipedia API function to get the list of Wikipedia Featured Articles?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware whether this is possible with a Wikipedia API function. However, it can be done using quite ordinary Python code.

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> import requests
```

Fetch the page that lists all of the featured articles.

```
>>> page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_articles').content
```

Parse it suitably for search purposes.

```
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page)
```

Assume that we're searching for the wikipedia article entitled 'Melbourne Castle'.

```
>>> wiki_title = 'Melbourne Castle'
```

Find any links with this title.

```
>>> links = tree.xpath('.//a[@href="/wiki/%s"]'%wiki_title.replace(' ', '_'))
```

If `links` is a non-empty list, meaning that a link to an article with the title 'Melbourne Castle' has been found, then print a suitable result, or otherwise.

```
>>> if links:
...     links[0].text + ' is a featured article'
... else:
...     links[0].text + ' is NOT a featured article'
... 
'Melbourne Castle is a featured article'
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most semantic and portable approach is checking for [Wikidata badges](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Badges) ([example](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=wbgetentities&format=json&sites=enwiki&titles=Melbourne%20Castle&props=sitelinks&sitefilter=enwiki&formatversion=2)) although the repsonse format is a bit obscure.

Alternatively, you can check for the featured article category via the `list=categorymembers` API module or for the featured article template via the `prop=transcludedin` module.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to do that.I could get all the pages in a Category using `Categorymembers` 
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers